# How to create view like radiogroup in android

Tags: android, view

I want to create a view which has three component, each component can be selected or not. If it is selected it has a icon on the topRight corner, and the other component which is selected before will be deselcted. And there is no radio indicator indicating which component is selected.

Comment: Question not cleared. Show your snapshot. May be you are talking about single selection.

Comment: I think you are talking about 3 RadioButtons in a RadioGroup?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Yes, almost. I want to put a RadioGroup but I don't want to add RadioButtons, which is not I needed. I want to add three custom view which can be selected and deselected.

Comment: See This http://blog.devminded.com/posts/custom-android-radiobutton

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting something like segment control of iOS in android then
[image]

[Example 1 android-segmented-control](https://github.com/hoang8f/android-segmented-control)

[Example 2 android-segmentedradiobutton](https://github.com/vinc3m1/android-segmentedradiobutton)